# Generating Hash Code for Object

Tags: .net, hashcode, gethashcode

I have a custom object (`DataPointCollection`) with two Integer properties and a Guid property. I want that object to generate a HashCode so that no two objects with the same values in those properties are added to a HashSet. I know I need to override the `GetHashCode()` method, but how do I do generate a hash code to accomplish this?

Here's how I want to use it.

```
Dim dataPointCollections As New HashSet(Of DataPointCollection)()

For Each row As DataRow In myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows

  Dim dataPointCollection As New DataPointCollection()
  dataPointCollection.ProjectID = row("ProjectID") 'Integer'
  dataPointCollection.RoleID = row("RoleID") 'Integer'
  dataPointCollection.ResourceGUID = row("ResourceGUID") 'Guid'

  If Not dataPointCollections.Contains(dataPointCollection) Then
    dataPointCollections.Add(dataPointCollection)
  End If

Next
```

I'm open to other ideas, but I thought this might be faster than doing a LINQ query on a collection of objects (there could be a very large number of these objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` - it's the combination of the two which will be used by the `HashSet`.

Your equality check should:

- Check that the other object is of the same type as this object (it's simpler if `DataPointCollection` is a sealed type; equality and inheritance are messy when combined)
- Compare the three fields for equality

Your hash code check needs to combine the three fields; the result *doesn't* have to be unique; for performance it's *better* if two unequal objects have a different hash code, but that's not required. The absolute requirement is that two equal objects *do* have the same hash code. I'd do something like this (C#, but easy to convert to VB):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    hash = hash * 31 + projectId;
    hash = hash * 31 + roleId;
    hash = hash * 31 + resourceGuid.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods in your `DataPointCollection` class, and use the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400) to generate the hash code.